# Does mmap changes flags stored in the page table?

Tags: x86, mmap, page-tables

To the best of my knowledge,

MMAP can be used to change a protection of mapped memory region.

For example, If I want to add executable permission

to one of my stack page

which is originally set as readable and writable permission

because of the Data execution policy(DEP).

And this permission is reflected on the page table flags such as W/XD in x86 architecture.

So my question is If I change the permission of the specific page using the MMAP,

does it request the kernel change the page table flags?

and does it automatically flush the TLB?

Thanks.

Comment: I think [you're looking for `mprotect(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html). It changes permissions for existing mappings. Calling it will do everything that's necessary for accesses to see the changes right away, e.g. TLB flushes on x86.    `mmap` with MAP_FIXED would discard the old mapping and map new zeroed pages into your stack space.  If you're getting crashes with mmap, that's probably why.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but if the mmap doesn't change the flags stored in the page table to reflect changed page permission, how the application code can change the R/W/X permission of their allocated pages? For exmaple, let's assume that I want to implement a simple virtual machines for generating the code on the fly and execute it. But for some reason, I want to set the page containing the generated code as R\W and change it R/W/X later. I have thought that mmap will request the kernel to call mprotect to change page table flags because the user process cannot directly invoke the mprotect.

Comment: If you already have pages, and just want to change permissions,  you call `mprotect(2)` yourself to ask the kernel to modify the page table and flush the TLB.  You only use `mmap(2)` if you want new pages.

Comment: But, you can pass the protection flags to the mmap function. Then what happens if you pass the address of your stack page which is already allocated? Does the mmap allocate new page? or only change the protection of that stack page?

Comment: Yeah, of course it needs to take permission args for *newly created* mappings.  It's like the different between `mkdir(2)` vs. `chmod(2)`.  Read the [`mmap(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) for the description of `MAP_FIXED`.  Like I already said, the new mapping will replace the existing mapping with a new zeroed page (assuming you used MAP_ANONYMOUS).  Without MAP_FIXED, it will pick a different address because the address you passed is already mapped.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, In C/C++ `mmap` wraps a system call of the same name. It is used to map a new **page-aligned** memory to the address space of the caller process. It lazily modifies the page-table meaning it only adds an entry to the `vm_area_struct` when called. Later on, when you first access the returned memory, a page table modification happens as the result of a page fault. So it only modifies the page table on first access. So it is clear that to allocate *new* pages (which is what `mmap` does), their protection flags must be known to `mmap`.

So as `mmap` is used to map *new* memory pages, `mprotect` is used to modify the protection flags/bits of an *already mapped* memory. It also modifies the page table so the new protection is known by all threads/processes that share the memory.

As I mentioned before, `mmap` and `mprotect` are both system calls that are executed in kernel mode; due to security reasons, no user-space process can modify its page table.

Hope this short answer helps.